# VAR models in R: Constant, Trend, Constant+Trend, None

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, trend, intercept

I currently apply a VAR models with the vars package in R. There are the options to select `"both"`, `"none"`, `"trend"`, or `"constant"`.

I searched a little but I didn't find conclusive evidence to know what `"const"` exactly means.

[image]

I found this plot and I'm curious, whether `"const"` means "cycle", also sometimes described as "drift"?

`"trend"` should be clear as a time series that is trending up- or downwards is trending. I assume most economic time series to be either constant+trend or constant?

Comment: I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 1):

> I found this plot and I'm curious, whether constant means "cycle", also sometimes described as "drift"?

`type=const` would include an intercept in the model equations.
I do not see how that could mean "cycle".
It could be interpreted as the drift term if the data supplied to the `VAR` function is a multivariate time series in first differences (rather than levels).

> I assume most economic time series to be either constant+trend or constant?

It is hard to generalize, but I guess you are right (if you mean a VAR with a constant or constant+trend, not just constant or constant+trend). But I am sure it is possible to find some examples where other options make more sense.