# Time Series: Examples for Drift, Drift + Trend, Trend

Tags: r, time-series, vector-autoregression

I started using R and applying the `vars` package in R. According to the documentation, there are the options to select `none`, `constant`, `trend`, or `both`.

I analyzed my time series and were able to plot the graphs, as shown below. However, some feedback on selecting the appropriate VAR model would be great.

The concept of a "trend" ([this post is good](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44647/which-dickey-fuller-test-should-i-apply-to-a-time-series-with-an-underlying-mode)) is clear, but visually detecting "constant", also known as "drift", or a time series with "non-zero mean", if I'm correct, seems little unclear.

1
[image]
2
[image]

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [this thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242101/var-models-in-r-constant-trend-constanttrend-none) but I cannot mark it as such as the answer in the other thread has no upvotes yet. Also, is the question more about the options of the `VAR` function in the `vars` package or about time series terminology ("constant", "drift", "trend", etc) in general?